# How to customize OOTB workflow emails

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, alert

How can I make simple format-type customizations to ALL OOTB workflow related emails?

I have found that many pre-Sharepoint 2010 posts indicated that OOTB workflow emails are in fact 'alerts', and therefore OOTB workflow emails could be customized using the same technique which is: making a customized version of alerttemplates.xml and even using `IAlertNotifyHandler` to intercept all alert emails.  However, it seems that OOTB workflow and workflow task emails are not affected by changes to my `customalerttemplates.xml` file (which I do follow with stsadm updatealerttemplates, iisreset, and timer service restart).

[This is what I used as a guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx) to customize alerts.

What am I missing?  Can OOTB workflow emails be customized?

Comment: You can "bump" your question by making an edit - it will again draw attention.  I suggest that you mention alerts in the title.  I tagged your question for you.

Comment: This is a similar question to one from a few days ago (Except yours is better worded) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51777/customize-the-email-notification-content-my-site-suggestions-email-job/51778#51778