# customize the email notification content - My Site Suggestions Email Job?

Tags: custom, email-templates

Is there a way to customize the Email content of "Here are some keyword suggestions for you!" sends by My Site Suggestions Email Job.

My Site Suggestions Email Job, sends out emails with colleague and keyword suggestions to people who don’t update their profiles often, prompting them to update their profiles, scheduled for every 15th of the month?

Answer (score 1):

This falls under [customising alert templates in which there are many blogs and posts on the subject.](http://www.alectang.com/blog/archive/2012/05/16/how-to-customise-sharepoint-alert-email-template.aspx)